# Reactjs array map mutation

Tags: reactjs

I have come around this topic today.

I am trying to map an array and update it like this.

```
 const editTask = (id, newTitle) => {
    const updatedTodo  = [...tasks].map(task => {
      task.id === id ? {...task, title: newTitle} : task
    });
    setTasks(updatedTodo);
  };
```

tasks is array of objects

One of my friends have told me that there is no need to copy the original array during map. because map itself returns the new array.

But as far as I know this array is considered as 2 level deep array and it needs to copy the original array too for the update of the object.

Can someone explain to me which way is correct and which is not? I am lost.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is right: `map` DOES return a new array (unlike `forEach`)

Since you're using react-hooks, creating a new array for the updated tasks is considered redundant and the best way to achieve the same result is to do something like this:

```js
const editTask = (id, newTitle) => {
  setTasks((tasks) =>
    tasks.map((task) => (task.id === id ? { ...task, title: newTitle } : task))
  );
};
```

Comment: If the solution worked for you, consider clicking the "check" icon. It'll help others with the same issue to identify the working solution.

Comment: I will be able to do it in 3 minutes